# Как свои пять пальцев

Tags: пунктуация, фразеология, как, сравнительный-оборот

"Как свои пять пальцев" - это, вроде как, фразеологизм. Но все равно засомневался: нужна ли перед ним запятая. Например, "знаю его(,) как свои пять пальцев".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если сравнительный оборот имеет характер устойчивого сочетания, то перед КАК запятая не ставится. В вашем случае оборот звучит не "как свои пять пальцев", а "**знать как свои пять пальцев**". В предложении пунктуация такая: Я знаю его как свои пять пальцев.